# Discordjs: how to listen for messages on a specific channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am building a discord bot to listen to messages on a specific channel. The issue is that my code listens to all channels.

Even if I use a condition to check for the channel id before picking the message, it means it will do more work than is necessary.

I want to avoid the case of selecting messages from multiple channels and just concentrate on the messages in the channel I want to listen to.

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const {TOKEN, CHANNEL_ID} = require('./src/config/index');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
  
});

client.once('ready', (c) => {
  console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  console.log(message)
})


client.login(TOKEN);
```

This code above is the current code I am using

Answer (score 3):

You can check where the message was posted before running any code.
As far as i am aware that is the only way to do this

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
 if (message.channel.id === "YOUR CHANNEL ID") {
   // run code here
 }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramy Hazem. It seems that way from all my searches but that sounds terrible to me. Imagine having to listen to 20 channels to get messages from a single channel when you know the channel you need to deal with.

Comment: i guess another possible option is only having your bot see that channel, set perms for that and maybe that could work?

Comment: Large scale bots listen to millions of messages across thousands of channels just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways of sending a message to a `specific channels`.

```
//1. Single channel listener
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
   if (message.channel.id === "channel_id") {
       //For a single channel listener.
   } else {
       //You can send a message if the channel_id is not equal.
   }
})

//2. Multiple channel listener / can be use as .json
let channels = [
    "channel_id",
    "channel_id"
]

if(channels.includes(message.channel.id)) {
    //Multiple Channel ID's
} else {
    //An example of return for not including some channel_id
    message.channel.send("I can't use these command on this channel.")
}

//3. Can be use like using a database such as mongodb / mongoose / etc.
let channels = {
    "chan": [
        "987627957478637619",
        "948780253948575764"
     ]
}

if(channels?.chan.includes(message.channel.id)) {
      //Multiple Channel ID's
} else {
      //An example of return for not including some channel_id
      message.channel.send("I can't use these command on this channel.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, pretty simple and it works.

```
let allowedChannels = [
  /*bot-channel*/"1053346645779152993",
  /*console*/"1053346646227959900"
];

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
  //VERY important, exit if the message is from a bot to prevent loops
  if (msg.author.bot) {
    return;
  };
  //Check if the channel is accepting bot commands
  if (allowedChannels.includes(msg.channel.id) === false) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).